# How to add Content-Type application/json in this request

Tags: php, json, rest

I need to send this Content-Type - application/json in headers of the request below. 
How to add Content-Type application/json in this function in a head's array?

```
function sendOrder($arField){

$body='{
}';

$head=array("Authorization: ".$data['scheme']." ".$data['token']);
$data=self::getData("https://example.com",$body,$head);
return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the existing line with:

```
$head=array("Authorization: ".$data['scheme']." ".$data['token'], "Content-Type: application/json");
```

Should be all you need to do.